# I can't change on to the next screen when progress bar animation is over

Tags: swift, swiftui, progress-bar

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
@State var percent: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        ProgressBar(width:200, height: 30, percent: percent)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeIn.speed(0.1)) {
                    while percent < 100 {
                        percent += 1
                    }
                    viewRouter.currentPage = .homepage
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Animation doesn't come to an end but immediately change the View to .homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another edit: try something like this test code:

```
        import SwiftUI
        
        @main
        struct TestApp: App {
            var body: some Scene {
                WindowGroup {
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
        }
        
        
struct ContentView: View {
    //@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @State var percent: CGFloat = 0
    @State var showHomePage = false
    
    func doProgress() {
        if percent < 100 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) {
                percent += 1
                doProgress()
            }
        } else {
            showHomePage.toggle()
            // viewRouter.currentPage = .homepage
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ProgressView("", value: percent, total: 100)
                .onAppear {
                    doProgress()
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("the next screen view"),
                    isActive: $showHomePage,
                    label: { EmptyView() } )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want changing the views to be animated and if i put the if statement out of the animation it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want now. I've updated my answer. Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn’t help.

Comment: Ok, maybe third time lucky. I've updated my answer again using a different approach. Let us know if this works for you.